# How do I add a link to items in menu for navigation drawer in android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, hyperlink, navigation-drawer

I am trying to add a link to my text so that when the user clicks the text it redirects him to a website, the text is under an item tag which is under a menu tag in my xml file, but I don't know how to make this work. This is what I added so far. This is the xml file for the content of my navigation drawer, the navigation drawer code is in my activty_main.xml which is already functioning.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_one"
        android:title="link3"
        android:text="@string/hyperlink"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_two"
        android:title="Settings" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_three"
        android:title="link1" />

</menu>
```

and this is what I added in my string.xml file

```
<string name="hyperlink"><a href="https://www.youtube.com/">start</a></string>
```

however the problem is that I don't know how to make it work. I don't know what to add to my mainactivity to make this work. This is what I added to my main activity but it obviously doesn't work.

```
MenuItem menuItem = findViewById(R.id.nav_one);
    menuItem.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

What do I have to change and add to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

simply use the listener of the drawer and on the required item use

```
startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(your link here in string format)))
```

it will open the link in the default browser of the device , this code is kotlin by the way. but java is same also just have to use the java syntax like instead of simple `Intent` you have to use `new Intent` let me know if you need have in converting this to java

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
```

Calls `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` internally to connect destinations to menu items - this is how a new destination is launched when you click a menu item. Navigation supports `<activity>` destinations, allowing you to start an activity when clicking on a menu item. You'd add an activity destination to your graph that uses the same id as your menu item:

```
<activity
  android:id="@+id/nav_login_activity"
  app:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
  app:data="https://www.your_url_here.com"/>
```

Then the default `setupWithNavController` will call `startActivity` for you.